# Copy on write vs illegal access

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel

In the linux kernel, how does the page fault handler distinguish between copy-on-write mechanism vs illegal memory access, when a process tries to access a page which is read-only ?

Comment: Detailed here: http://linux-kernel-prog.net/O.Reilly-Understanding.the.Linux.Kernel.Second.Edition/0596002130_linuxkernel2-chp-8-sect-4.html

Answer (score 3):

The `do_page_fault()` function in `arch/<arch>/mm/fault.c` "demultiplexes" the various reasons why a page fault can occur, and passes control to an appropiate handler.

Answer (score 3):

If the faulting page is in the userspace region of the address space, the page fault handler looks up the memory map of the current task.  If the page is within a writable VMA (and the fault is a write fault) then it knows that it's a COW fault.